# Lining up equations with words

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I want to align the following assignment statements w.r.t the `=` sign as follows:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item  $Wd  =$ We are eating the fish.
\item  $Ct  =$ Your Claws tore through my shirt!
\item  $Dhw =$ Your Dolphin swims fast.
\end{itemize}
```

I guess I could use `begin{align*}` and then use `\text{}` but that seems really messy. I actually would like similar use to `begin{align}` where we can use the `&` character to determine the position of the alignment.

1. Is there a better way?
2. What else can you recommend?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And which is the desired alignment? Math expressions aligned at the `=` sign? Please describe in a little more detail the desired alignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the desired result, you could use `align*` (for a centered expression) or `flalign*` (for a flushed left expression):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{align*}
Wd &= \text{We are eating the fish.} \\
Ct &= \text{Your Claws tore through my shirt!} \\
Dhw &= \text{Your Dolphin swims fast.}
\end{align*}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{flalign*}
Wd &= \text{We are eating the fish.} & \\
Ct &= \text{Your Claws tore through my shirt!} \\
Dhw &= \text{Your Dolphin swims fast.}
\end{flalign*}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I think that using the equality sign for defining expressions (equating math and text) is not really correct. I would rather use one of the two options below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item $Wd$ represents... 
\item $Ct$ represents... 
\item $Dhw$ represents... 
\end{itemize}

$Wd$ represents..., $Ct$ represents..., and $Dhw$ represents...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It should probably be `\mathit{Wd}`

Answer (score 0):

If you desire to use the `itemize` environment, you can also use the `\makebox` macro to ensure that the text is right aligned to the widest text.

[image]

### Notes:

- This assumes that the description text is short enough to fit on one line.  If longer text is to be allowed, and desire that the text all begin at the same horizontal spot then other options such as using a `\parbox`, or `tabular` could be used.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\LargestText}{$Dhw =$}%
\newcommand*{\MakeBox}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{\LargestText}][r]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item  \MakeBox{$Wd  =$} We are eating the fish.
    \item  \MakeBox{$Ct  =$} Your Claws tore through my shirt!
    \item  \MakeBox{$Dhw =$} Your Dolphin swims fast.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```